# about 'zsh react-native command not found' AFTER SETTING PATH

Tags: macos, react-native, zsh

Some time ago, I had the command not found error when running expo, so I set path at `~/.bash_profile` and so, after running source ~/.bash_profile, now I can call expo without problems.

Today, I tried running react-native link and the following error appeared:
`zsh: react-native command not found`

What else could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't have [react native cli](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli) installed globally, which is good as it's not needed.

Check in the project directory if react-native is installed
so `./node_modules/react-native/` should exist and has something inside.

If so, you don't need to run `react-native` directly; try running through `npx react-native` or npm script.

If not, make sure you have react-native in `package.json` dependencies section, and run `npm install` to pull the react-native library folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! using npx react-native link worked!!